# Images in App looks Blurry

Tags: android, graphics

I have developed an application in Android,and followed all design guideline in it.
But when i run app on Device images looks blurry(less sharper).

Can anyone tell me what actually the problem is?

Or

What are the guidelines followed by Graphic Designer while designing the graphics for Android application?

Answer (score 2):

You can try 9-patch image which is nothing but a stretchable bitmap image.Check following links for more details
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: I have near about 50 images,so i have to create all images into 9 patch images....

Comment: Is there any guideline which designer can follow while creating Graphics?

Comment: @user880006: You can try it for all images or only for blur images.
Creating 9-patch images helps to keep your image same across all device and resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely your interpretation of what Android is doing behind the scenes to scale the images to look *right on whatever screen you're looking at them on.

Try manually setting the layout_width and layout_height to the actual dimensions of the images with px (rather than dip) and see if that makes it look sharp. If so, you'll want to create different versions for different resolutions.

You don't want to leave them set to their pixel widths, just do it to see if that's what's causing it.

Comment: But when i use same image in Iphone,then it looks sharper...?

Comment: I don't know how iPhone renders things. I'm just telling you how Android scales things... it doesn't preserve the exact original image, it's scales it depending on the device's resolution.